# iOS push notification and build number

Tags: xcode, swift, push-notification

Since I release the new version of my app from 1.0.1 to 1.0.2 I notice that the push notification stop work, it still working in parse I can see all the been sent out, also if I try to create a new campaign in parse.com and send it out noboby receives it anymore, what do I have to do to allow this new app version to use the push notification?

Comment: There's no relation between the two. Maybe your certificates changed. That means you need to update parse with the new certificates.

Comment: @SamhanSalahuddin Yes you was right the number change was coincidental with the release from internal to external testing where the certificates had to be update from developer to production. thanks

Answer (score 1):

If someone find similar problems the number change was coincidental with the release from internal to external testing and the certificates had to be update from developer to production.

For some reason even the internal testers stop work, however once I generate a production key and install in parse everything start to work again, for internal and external testers.